# openmp: seq processing within subroutine

Tags: fortran, openmp, subroutine

I would like to carry out calculations in parallel by calling

```
 !$OMP PARALLEL
    call sub
 !$OMP END PARALLEL
```

this fires of n (= no. of threads) calls to`sub`, as desired.

within sub, I am reading from separate data files, with the file and the no. of reads determined from the thread number. This works if I enclose everything in `sub` in `!$OMP ORDERED` ... `!$OMP END ORDERED`.
however, this also causes all threads to run strictly sequentially, i.e. thread 0 runs first and all reads in it are complete before thread 1 starts, etc.

what I would like to achieve though is that all n threads run concurrently  and only processing within a thread is sequentially (as reads are from different data files). any idea how? replacing `ORDERED` by `TASK` does not help.

Comment: Unless you have a parallel file system don't expect multiple threads reading from multiple files 'simultaneously' to improve the performance of (that part of) your code.  Expect, instead, that contention for access to a single i/o channel will slow the overall execution of (that part of) your program.  As for any more specific advice, without sight of your code it's very difficult.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes, I did create separate files for each thread = paralllel file system, determining the unit no to read from as a function of the thread no & declaring the unit no. as thereadprivate

Comment: I don't know if you understand the term parallel filesystem correctly. They can be found in supercomputers, e.g., Lustre.

Comment: @VladimirF thanks! I obviously did not. But even if I cannot read  from several threads at the time, it would help a lot being able to do the subsequent calculations in the subroutine more or less simultaneously until the next chunk of data is read. I've tried various combinations/permutations of ordered and critical, but didn't get it yet.